# extjs - CheckboxModel and RowExpander can't be used together?

Tags: extjs4

EXTJS Version: 4.07

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        rowBodyTpl : [ '<p>......</p>' ]
    }],
    ...other config stuff...
}
```

Running this code in the browser results in the following error at line 15 in ext-all.js.

"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getEditor'"

Disabling either one of the two plugins stops the error. Any workaround/fix and/or further insight into this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i remember reading something about grid plugins being finicky around the order of inclusion. Try switching them around.

Comment: @DmitryB, my god, you are my hero! Simply switching the order of inclusion fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading something about grid plugins being finicky around the order of inclusion. Try switching them around.

...posting so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

can't check checkboxes in checkboxmodel

Many thanks dbrin.  I'd add a comment to that answer, but no rep.
That answer led to a solution that fixed a problem that was really giving me a lot of trouble.

if I declared the checkbox model in the def

```
selModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {} )
```

and the cell editing in the init:

```
me.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
    clicksToEdit: 1
});
me.plugins = [me.cellEditing],
```

it would sometimes work but not always (failure was you couldn't check the checkboxes).

Putting them both in the init, fixed it (regardless of the order):

```
me.selModel = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel({});
me.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
    clicksToEdit: 1
});
me.plugins = [me.cellEditing],
```

By the way, if I declared the cell editing outside the init in the definition, it totally messed up the page.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @Qix This user seems to make an attempt at answering the question as well.

Comment: @Kermit It's both a thank you post as well as another issue the user appears to be having. It's a stretch to say their fix is an answer. It could fall into multiple categories for VTD.